# Show horizontal scroll bar on ios

Tags: ios, css, scroll, safari, scrollbar

I want to show a scroll bar at all times on ios devices. using this css below works vertically but not horizontally, anyone know how?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    display: block;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just needed to add height to `::-webkit-scrollbar`

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have overflow-scrolling set to touch.

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
```

As far as i know you can't have momentum scrolling and a styled scrollbar

Comment: Yeah i had that, was just the height issue I answered above for my problem, this is a good answer for people that have the height and its still not showing :)

Comment: Yep, posted purely for other users who found themselves here like i did and had a height and still wasn't working.